# Flutter GetX Snackbar Actions

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx, snackbar

I was wondering how to implement GetX's Snackbar but with actions. I know how to write SnackbarActions on the usual ScaffoldSnackbar provided with Flutter. I was wondering if there was a way to get this same functionality in GetX's Snackbar. As you may be able to guess, I am trying to implement an undo functionality, and I wrote the rest of my app with GetX Snackbars.

This is how I know how to show a Snackbar with Actions

```dart
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(
                              content:
                                  Text("Deleted ${item.matchNumber.value}"),
                              action: SnackBarAction(
                                label: "Undo",
                                onPressed: () => controller.documentsHelper
                                    .saveMatchData(item),
                              ),
                              duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
                            ),
                          );
```

How would get this functionality through GetX? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get snackbar has parameter called mainButton you can use it to create your action button

```
 Get.snackbar(
  'Snackbar',
  'Deleted ${item.matchNumber.value}',
  colorText: Colors.black,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
  maxWidth: Get.width,
  mainButton: TextButton(
    child: Text('Undo'),
    onPressed: () {
      // Implement your action here
    },
  ),
);
```